# simple bash function does not understand git

Tags: bash

I have git installed on my machine using homebrew as you can see below.

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.3.4
```

I am learning bash programming and I have following function in my ~/.bashrc

```
function gitlab {
  CMD= "git --version"
  $CMD
}
```

However when I run gitlab I get following output

```
$ gitlab
-bash: git --version: command not found
```

I am using bash on mac.

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the space after `CMD=`. This evaluates to `CMD=<empty string> "git --version"`. First, the environment variable `CMD` is set to an empty string, then the command `git --version` is called. Notice that due to the `"..."` the shell really tries to execute a command `git --version` and not `git` with argument `--version`. Simple remove the space between `=` and `"` to fix this.

Comment: +1 as you're right. I didn't see that space. I read the question too quickly.

Comment: You got it . It was the space. For others yes I can use alias but this example was a snapshot of a bigger function. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You are running the entire string as a single command. It is possible to have a binary called `foo bar` (*with* a space), and you would run it just as you showed.

Edit: What are you actually trying to do? There's no need to store a command in a variable before running it:

```
gitlab() {git --version}
```

and

```
alias gitlab='git --version'
```

both do the same as you were expecting from the function above. In general, the function solution is recommended above the alias (and you don't need to prefix it with `function`).

Comment: I don't follow you. Can you elaborate. Also what do I need to change to fix it.

Comment: You've only got it half-right, I'm afraid :-) See my comment to Sylvain Defrsne.

Answer (score 0):

There is a superfluous space after the `=` when you try to assign the string `"git --version"` to the `CMD` variable. The shell think this is an assignation of an empty string to the `CMD` variable that is only local to the next command. As your command is quoted with `"`, the shell try to execute a program called `git --version`. As no such program exist, it fails.

Your function is interpreted almost like the following function (the error is easier to see here):

```
function() {
    CMD=
    "git --version"
    unset -v CMD
    $CMD
}
```

You should remove the space character to have it interpreted like you intended. However, there are easier way to do the same thing:

```
function gitlab() {
    git --version
}
```

If you what you wanted was to store the result of the `git --version` execution to be stored in the `CMD` variable, you should have done it this way:

```
function gitlab() {
    VERSION="$(git --version)"
    echo "$VERSION"
}
```

Edit: corrected my reply as it was incorrect (error spotted by @DarkDust).

Comment: Not quite. He is *not* assigning the command to the variable `CMD`, notice the space after the equals sign. `CMD="git --version" ; $CMD` would evaluate just fine, but `CMD= "git --version" ; $CMD` is what he's doing.

Comment: You're right ! D'oh ! Correcting my answer, just for my own sake.